# Imagebutton poor performance in grid layout

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-gridlayout, android-imagebutton

i have this layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="2">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main_Quote_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/quote_btn"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_btn"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/contact_btn"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery_btn"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_scroll_txt"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/scroll_txt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the result is this, but the screen has a lot of lag and Nav Menu open slowly.
[image]

when i delete "layout_columnWeight" from imagebuttons, the position of buttons is not that i need but screen run smoothly.

it seems imagebuttons in gridlayout with weight ,have poor performance.

i need a screen with four imagebutton like above and i have no idea.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you can use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton` , and use `Glide` library to load the images to the views which will increase the performance of the application read more https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: How big are your images? Large images can take up a lot of memory, thus slowing down your application...

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović the image have 400px * 400px size, is this size too big ? so how can i find true size for this imagebuttons for different layout sizes ?

Comment: @AlexMercer I'm not sure, it depends on the size of your display, but that size is not too big...

Comment: @MohamedRa Thanks Mohamed ! i use Glide now and it work like a charm ! no lag anymore !!!